# CSS not working in HTML file - potential browser issue?

Tags: html, css

this is baffling me.

As I was writing CSS and testing it in my browser (safari 12.1), I noticed things weren't working as I expected, so I tried testing a few things out.

I literally copy and pasted some HTML and accompanying CSS from codepen (to test) and the CSS is only applying the very basic text-align and things like that.

Am I missing something? Do I need to change some settings or do something else to the CSS/HTML files to get it to work? I'm so confused...

I've attached a screenshot of how it's being displayed in my safari window too.

HTML:

```
<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<h1>RESPONSIVE PRICING TABLE DESIGN <br> BY <a target="blank" href="http://www.digimadmedia.com">DIGIMAD MEDIA</h1>

<div class="price-table-wrapper">
  <div class="pricing-table">
    <h2 class="pricing-table__header">- BASIC -</h2>
    <h3 class="pricing-table__price">£50</h3>
    <a target="_blank" class="pricing-table__button" href="http://www.digimadmedia.com">
      Join Now!
    </a>
    <ul class="pricing-table__list">
      <li>30 day free trial</li>
      <li>50gb storage space</li>
      <li>20% discount</li>
      <li>24 hour support</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="pricing-table featured-table">
    <h2 class="pricing-table__header">- BUSINESS -</h2>
    <h3 class="pricing-table__price">£80</h3>
    <a target="_blank" class="pricing-table__button" href="http://www.digimadmedia.com">
      Join Now!
    </a>
    <ul class="pricing-table__list">
      <li>40 day free trial</li>
      <li>100gb storage space</li>
      <li>25% discount</li>
      <li>24 hour support</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="pricing-table">
    <h2 class="pricing-table__header">- PREMIUM -</h2>
    <h3 class="pricing-table__price">£130</h3>
    <a target="_blank" class="pricing-table__button" href="http://www.digimadmedia.com">
      Join Now!
    </a>
    <ul class="pricing-table__list">
      <li>50 day free trial</li>
      <li>200gb storage space</li>
      <li>40% discount</li>
      <li>24 hour support</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  a {
    color: #66cccc;
  }
}

.price-table-wrapper {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;

  .featured-table {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
  }

  .pricing-table {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: white;
    margin: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

    &__header {
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #909090;
      background: #e0e0e0;
    }
    &__price {
      color: #66cccc;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: auto;
      font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    &__button {
      display: block;
      background: #66cccc;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 20px;
      color: white;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

      &:before {
        position: absolute;
        left: -20%;
        top: -10%;
        content: "";
        width: 60%;
        height: 220%;
        transform: rotate(-30deg);
        background: white;
        opacity: 0.3;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      }

      &:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: ">";
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        font-size: 25px;
        padding: 15px;
        padding-right: 40px;
        color: white;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      }

      &:hover {
        background: black;
      }
    }
    &__list {
      padding: 20px;
      color: #a0a0a0;
      li {
        padding: 15px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #c8c8c8;

        &:last-child {
          border: none;
        }
      }
    }

    &:hover {
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);

      .pricing-table__button {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 35px;
        &:before {
          top: -80%;
          transform: rotate(0deg);
          width: 100%;
        }
        &:after {
          opacity: 1;
          padding-right: 15px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: codepen test result]

Comment: Did you test this in a different browser? Clear your cache? Disable and addons/plugins/extensions? Check the browser's console?

Comment: @j08691 Yes i've tried in Google Chrome also, exactly the same thing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS isn't CSS. It is SCSS and needs transpiling to CSS with a SASS tool before a browser can make use of it.

See [the SASS website](https://sass-lang.com/) for more details.

CodePen indicates this by putting SCSS in brackets.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much! I would never have known this!